# Performing a test on heteroskedasticity and the interpretation of the results

Tags: stata, panel-data, heteroscedasticity

I ran a test for heteroskedasticity in the panel data I am using and got the following output (performed in `Stata`):

```
. xtgls  overall opm  tadiv10m auditcomm nplsgrossloan govauditor, panels(heteroskedastic) corr(independent)

Cross-sectional time-series FGLS regression

Coefficients:  generalized least squares
Panels:        heteroskedastic
Correlation:   no autocorrelation

Estimated covariances      =         6          Number of obs      =      1236
Estimated autocorrelations =         0          Number of groups   =         6
Estimated coefficients     =         6          Time periods       =       206
                                                Wald chi2(5)       =    501.35
                                                Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     overall |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         opm |   .0376394   .0041554     9.06   0.000     .0294949    .0457839
    tadiv10m |   .0000537   .0000138     3.89   0.000     .0000267    .0000807
   auditcomm |   .0739684   .0118756     6.23   0.000     .0506927    .0972441
nplsgrossl~n |   .2631301   .0280739     9.37   0.000     .2081062    .3181539
  govauditor |  -.0606564   .0058305   -10.40   0.000     -.072084   -.0492288
       _cons |   .5981386    .004728   126.51   0.000     .5888719    .6074053
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could someone help me interpret the meaning of the results above?

Comment: Related to this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137551/hausman-test-for-panel-data If this is for homework or assignment purposes please add the [self-study] tag to your question.

Comment: I don't think you have run a test. It looks that you have estimated a panel data model using GLS with the assumption that error variance matrix $\Omega$ is diagonal (no covariance between errors) (`panels(heteroskedastic)`) but the error variance may differ between panels. You also assume the errors are uncorrelated across time (`corr(independent)`). The function you are using is explained in [this manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtgls.pdf). What do you find unclear?